# Can I change a dataset inside a custom object and then notify the adapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, notifydatasetchanged

What I want to know is, if I set an adapter to a recyclerview like this:

```
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new myRecyclerAdapter(mCustomObject.getDataSet()));
```

Can I update the dataset and notify the adapter like this?

```
mCustomObject.getDataSet().add(XPTO);
myRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Or do I need to get the dataset inside the adapter?

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: use `gettter setter` and get your dataset class on the position and set the new data,call and `notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: Sorry, i didnt understood :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `mCustomObject.getDataSet()` always returns the same object and doesn't create a new one, that should be enough. If it returns a new object every time, then the adapter has no way of updating the values to display.

Comment: Thanks, I guess this is the answer I needed. Cause I need this dataset inside the object.

Comment: Indeed. A suggestion: it might be easier for you to have a `myRecylerAdapter.setData(mCustomObject)` and that internally gets the needed data (`mCustomObject.getDataSet()` in this case)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple methods [notify***()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html). To be efficient use it with position.

Comment: I know, I just was more simple.

Answer (score 0):

assume you have your data in a list like

```
List<MyData> dataSet;
```

and MyData is like

```
public class MyData {
String name;
String id;
public MyData(String n,String i){
this.name=n;
this.id=i;
}
//getter setter
public void setName(String n){
name=n;
}
public String getName(){
return name;
}
.
.
.
//Creates Empty Constructor
public MyData(){
}
```

set the data

```
MyData mydata=new MyData();
mydata.setName("One");
mydata.setId("one");
dataSet.add(mydata);
//for more data add the data in a loop.
```

set the Adapter.

```
MyData mydata=(MyData)datas.get(position);
String name1 =mydata.getName(); //get your name here
mydata.setName("give a diffrent name"); //you changed the name on this position
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Lets suppose that I already have setted the adapter. The RecyclerView is already showing the itens. So, the user add an item to the list.
My question is:
- do I need to add this new item to the list inside the adapter?
- or can I set this new item to the list inside the object and the adapter know its source and update itself correctly?